# how to interpret O(1) + O(2) + ... + O(n)?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

in the book ***"Introduction to algorithms"(CLRS) page 49*** it says:

> "The number of anonymous functions in an expression is understood to
>   be equal to the number of times the asymptotic notation appears. For
>   example, in the expression:
>
> $\sum_{i=1}^n O(i)$
>
> there is only a single anonymous function (a function of i). This
>   expression is thus not the same as $O(1) + O(2) + O(3) + ... + O(n)$,
>   which doesn’t really have a clean interpretation."

what is the difference between these 2 equitions and how should interpret each one??

Comment: This is a really unfortunate case of the widespread abuse of notation causing unnecessary confusion. I hope the links above help you; if not, please edit to clarify what remains unclear and we can reopen.